# Ruby on Rails 3, Email Validation for Multiple Domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email-validation

hey guys, I'm running into a issue here. Is there a way to have TWO acceptable email formats?

You see, the site I'm building needs to have users register with a certain domain, and the student, and staff share different domains. For Example: name@mail.domain.ac.uk, and name@domain.ac.uk. I want tutors, and students to be able to sign up. I've tried this so far:

```
EMAIL_STAFF_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@mail.domain.ac.uk/i
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@domain.ac.uk/i

validates :email, :presence   => true,
                  :format     => { :with => email_regex,
                                   :with => EMAIL_STAFF_REGEX},}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are splitting the regexp's out because you want to be able to use the regexp later to tell if they are a tutor or student.

Try

```
tutor_subdomain = mail
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+-.]+@(:?#{tutor_domain}.)?domain.ac.uk/i
TUTOR_REGEX = /\A[\w+-.]+@#{tutor_domain}.domain.ac.uk/i

def tutor?
  email =~ TUTOR_REGEX
end
```

I would recommend making the tutor column an actual field so you can do queries on it and then use validations to make sure that the email matches the same format.

```
validates:email, :format => {:with => STUDENT_REGEX}
validates:email, :format => {:with => TUTOR_REGEX}, :if => :tutor?
```